# JQuery UI Spinner is not updating ng-model in angular

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

Angular's ng-model is not updating when using jquery-ui spinner.

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gCzg7/1/

```
<div ng-app>

  <div ng-controller="SpinnerCtrl">
    <input type="text" id="spinner" ng-model="spinner"/><br/>
    Value: {{spinner}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#spinner').spinner({});
</script>
```

If you update the text box by typing it works fine (you can see the text change).  But if you use the up or down arrows the model does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charminbear is right about needing $scope.$apply().  Their were several problems with this approach however.  The 'change' event only fires when the spinner's focus is removed.  So you have to click the spinner then click somewhere else.  The 'spin' event is fired on each click.   In addition, the model needs to be updated before $scope.$apply() is called.

Here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3PVdE/

```
$timeout(function () {
        $('#spinner').spinner({
            spin: function (event, ui) {
                var mdlAttr = $(this).attr('ng-model').split(".");

                if (mdlAttr.length > 1) {

                    var objAttr = mdlAttr[mdlAttr.length - 1];
                    var s = $scope[mdlAttr[0]];

                    for (var i = 0; i < mdlAttr.length - 2; i++) {
                        s = s[mdlAttr[i]];
                    }

                    s[objAttr] = ui.value;
                } else {
                    $scope[mdlAttr[0]] = ui.value;
                }

                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }, 0);
    });
```

Here's a similar question and approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/12167566/584761

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, but... there's a very simple and clean "Angular way" to make sure that the spinner's `spin` events handle the update against `ngModel` without resorting to `$apply` (and especially without resorting to `$parse` or an emulation thereof).

All you need to do is define a *very* small directive with two traits:

1. The directive is placed as an attribute on the input element you want to turn into a spinner; and
2. The directive configures the spinner such that the `spin` event listener calls the `ngModel` controller's `$setViewValue` method with the `spin` event value.

Here's the directive in all its clear, tiny glory:

```
function jqSpinner() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, c) {
            element.spinner({
                spin: function (event, ui) {
                    c.$setViewValue(ui.value);
                }
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Note that [`$setViewValue`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) is intended for exactly this situation:

> This method should be called when an input directive wants to change
>   the view value; typically, this is done from within a DOM event
>   handler.

Here's a link to [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8bab9bh7/).

---

If the demo link provided above dies for some reason, here's the full example script:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController)
        .directive('jqSpinner', jqSpinner);

    function ExampleController() {
        var c = this;
        c.exampleValue = 123;
    };

    function jqSpinner() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, c) {
                element.spinner({
                    spin: function (event, ui) {
                        c.$setViewValue(ui.value);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

And the minimal example template:

```
<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleController as c">
    <input jq-spinner ng-model="c.exampleValue" />
    <p>{{c.exampleValue}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry to bring this back from the dead. But I'm having the same issue. My problem is when I attach this directive to my input field, upon clicking the arrows-- i get the error: "element.spinner is not a function"? It's being read just fine in my controller. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Kode_12 Are you including both jQuery and jQuery UI before including Angular? What versions of each are you using? Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle or plunk? How do you mean "being read just fine in my controller"? (Sorry for the question barrage, it's just stream of consciousness.)

Comment: No worries! I have Angular (1.6.4) bootstrapped before jQuery (3.2.1), and lastly jQuery UI (1.12.1), I tried flipping the jQuery libraries to load first but that didn't change anything. I wish I could produce a fiddle, but being work related, I can't :((

Comment: So in my controller, I can invoke the .spinner method successfully, and it works--meaning the input field increments and decreases by clicking the up and down arrows. But the arrows still don't trigger Angular to run and update the fields.

Comment: @Kode_12 It sounds like there must be something wrong inside the `spin` event handler specified in the object you're passing to the `spinner` method. Try setting a breakpoint on that line (i.e. where `$setViewValue` is invoked) and see what the various in-scope values are (e.g. what are the values of `c`, `ui`, `ui.value`, etc). If the breakpoint is never hit (when you click the up/down arrows), that means the `spinner` options object isn't being constructed and/or passed in correctly.

Comment: So the problem is because I have 2 input fields that I'm attaching the directive to. A columns and a rows input. This is inside the link function:            $("#row-count").spinner({
                spin: function (event, ui) {
                    c.$setViewValue(ui.value);
                    console.log(element);
                    console.log(this.getElementsByClassName());
                }
            });
            $("#column-count").spinner({
                spin: function (event, ui) {
                    c.$setViewValue(ui.value);
                }
            });

Comment: So what happens is the "column-count'' id input is the only one that gets updated, because it's the bottom most spinner invocation. That being said, a dirty solution would be to simply create 2 identical directives (1 for the column input I have, and another for the rows input). Is there a cleaner way of doing this? Maybe some kind of if/else statement I could include in the link function? I can open a new question, but the main question is: how can I update ng-model for multiple inputs using the jquery spinner? --sorry for the lengthy comment!!

Comment: Here is what my inputs look like:  <input type="number" id="column-count" jq-spinner ng-model="columns" />  <input type="number" id="row-count" jq-spinner ng-model="rows" />

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is showing something else.

Besides this: Angular can not know about any changes that occur from outside its scope without being aknowledged.
If you change a variable of the angular-scope from OUTSIDE angular, you need to call the `apply()`-Method to make Angular recognize those changes. Despite that implementing a spinner can be easily achieved with angular itself, in your case you must:
1. Move the spinner inside the SpinnerCtrl
2. Add the following to the SpinnerCtrl:

```
   $('#spinner').spinner({
      change: function( event, ui ) {
           $scope.apply();
       }
   }
```

If you really need or want the jQuery-Plugin, then its probably best to not even have it in the controller itself, but put it inside a directive, since all DOM-Manipulation is ment to happen within directives in angular. But this is something that the AngularJS-Tutorials will also tell you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I updated the fiddle.  Your change doesn't appear to work, even in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

as @Charminbear said angular is not aware of the change.
However the problem is not angular is not aware of a change to the model rather that it is not aware to the change of the input.

here is a directive that fixes that:

```
directives.directive('numeric', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).spinner({
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    $(element).change();
                } 
            });
        };
    });
```

by running `$(element).change()` you inform angular that the input has changed and then angular updates the model and rebinds.
note `change` runs on blur of the input this might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but I do it by updating the model with the ui.value in the spin event. Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garywdean/gCzg7/2/).

```
function SpinnerCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $('#spinner').spinner({
            spin: function (event, ui) {
                $scope.spinner = ui.value;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

If this method is "wrong", any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that updates the model like coder’s solution, but it uses $parse instead of parsing the ng-model parameter itself.

```js
app.directive('spinner', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).spinner({
            spin: function(event, ui) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope._spinnerVal = = element.val();
                        $parse(attrs.ngModel + "=_spinnerVal")(scope);
                        delete scope._spinnerVal;
                    });
                }, 0);
            }
        });
    };
});
```