# AngularJS - jQuery UI - binding issue when ng-csv used

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I am trying to add  date picker to my HTML page where I am doing data binding using angular js. I have also a requirement to export the data to CSV file which I am doing using ng-csv directive.

I have tried the question present in stack over flow

[AngularJS - jQuery UI - binding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727207/angularjs-jquery-ui-binding-issue)

Here is my fiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/DivB/4uae2gor/3/

html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p><b>Date from</b> <input id="date1" value="1/1/1980"  ng-model="fromDate" my-datepicker /></p>
    <p><b>Data do:</b> <input id="date2" value="1/1/1980" ng-model="toDate" my-datepicker /></p>
    Choosen date from: {{fromDate}} to: {{toDate}}
    <br />
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-csv="getArray" csv-header="getHeader()" filename="CO_Status.csv" field-separator=","><span>Export to CSV</span></button> </br>
</div>
```

and script

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives','ngSanitize','ngCsv']);
function MainCtrl($scope) {   
$scope.getHeader = function () {return ["CO Number", "Client Name" ]};  
$scope.getArray = [ {A:"a",B:"b"},{A:"c",B:"d"}     ];                                          
 }
     angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
   .directive('myDatepicker', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {     
 element.datepicker({
     changeYear : true,
     changeMonth : true,
     appendText : '(yyyy-mm-dd)',
     dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd', 
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {                     
                var mdlAttr = $(this).attr('ng-model');
                scope[attrs.ngModel] = dateText;                    
                scope.$apply();                                                   
            }                
    });
}
  });
```

If I remove all the stuff related to ng-csv(External resources ng-csv and sanitize, include 'ngcsv' and 'ngSanitize' in app module) for  the code works. But together it doesn't works.

Can anyone please help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really not clear what your specific problem is. You mention both datepicker and csv. Code won't stop working without throwing errors...what are they? Why are you including duplicates of all your scripts?

Comment: Also, why do you include both minified and un-minified js files? You're now having duplicate js files of allmost everything. I suggest you only add the minified versions (all min.js files) and leave the bigger ones out, for faster loading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . . i am very new to angularjs and jquery. I don't have access to my code now . I will give more details about my code on minday

Comment: I have added fiddle which is not working..https://jsfiddle.net/DivB/4uae2gor/3/

Answer (score 0):

Below way works for me now

only add CDN's in below order

1. jquery
2. jquery ui
3. angular js
4. angular-sanitize
5. ng-csv

I have used bootstarp along with above which is added in the very beginning. Rest are not required

Edit your html as below

```
<p><b>Date from</b> <input id="date1" datepicker date="fromDate" /></p>
```

Add below directive in your script

```
myApp.directive('datepicker',function(){
  return{
    scope:{
    date: "="
    },
    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('date', function(value){
            $(element).datepicker('setDate',value);
        }),
        $(function(){
            $(element).datepicker({
                       changeYear : true,
            changeMonth : true,
            appendText : '(dd/mm/yyyy)',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                onSelect:function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });

        });
    }
}
})
```